# Appending String From Variable To HTML Element Using PHP

Tags: php, html

<del>I am trying to append a string, which was stored in a variable, to a HTML element. I wrote the function below which works fine but I am getting the "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::appendChild()" error message once I add new post.</del>

**UPDATE**

I thought that the given before information is irrelevant, so I just need to know the way how to add the string below to an HTML in the commented place.

PHP

```
$string = "some text";
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>some content</div>
    <div>some content</div>
    <div>some content</div>
    <!--Place where I need to add the string same as it is-->
</div>
```

Comment: isn't `appendChild()` javascript? Why are you executing it as PHP?

Comment: @aron9forever `DOMNode::appendChild` is a perfectly valid PHP method from the XML Manipulation library [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php)

Comment: @Ties you're right, I looked it up right after posting the comment unfortunately.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use DOM Manipulation tools or do you just don't know how to insert html from php in a more simple way?

Comment: I have three pages (index which is home page, and two external template and example) in the template I have only one post template which I don't want to hardcode every time I need to add a new post. In the example page I have some unique content which will be in every single post. My idea is that when I add a nex content to example page, PHP function sees that classes amount have changed and includes a new post to main page. Everything works great I just don't know how to add the string in variable to the dom :)

Answer (score 0):

<s>You didn't post you full code but I'm assuming you have an `DOMXPath` where you call the `query` method on.</s>

**Edit:** You did post your full code and you are using `DOMXPath`

---

This method returns an `DOMNodeList`, a list that contains `DOMNode`s.

You can only call `appendChild` on a single `DOMNode` as the method is not defined on `DOMNodeList`.

Use this to get the first `DOMNode` from the `DOMNodeList`:

```
$wrapper->item(0)->appendChild($newpost);
```

This gets the first item from the list for you on which you can call the `appendChild` method.

### Insert template

This line won't work:

```
$newpost = "<?php echo include('/assets/includes/post-template.php'); ?>";
```

As that is PHP code you're trying to insert as DOM/HTML

Do this instead:

```
// New temp document
$templateDoc = new DOMDocument();
// Load your template file into this document
$templateDoc->loadHTMLFile($DOCUMENT_ROOT . '/assets/includes/post-template.php')
// Get all immediate children of your template document
$templateElements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('*');
```

And inside your `if`-statement:

```
foreach($templateElements as $templateElement){
    // Append all children to your wrapper
    $wrapper->item(0)->appendChild($templateElement);
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code, you could review it. I have used the method you suggested but it does not help as well unfortunately.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode

Comment: When I dump the $wrapper variable I get this: object(DOMNodeList)#8 (1) { ["length"]=> int(1) } This is wrapper:

Comment: @EmilGurbanov that's another error, added some code to my answer

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::appendChild() :))

Comment: When I copy and manually add the string to my html it does everything it is used for, the only problem is to add the string using conditions. When I am dumping all variable they are ok, function also ok. Maybe appendChild is not best option for my purpose.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught DOMException: Hierarchy Request Error :)